# Changing the "From" of a Draft Object

Tags: gmail-api

If you change the From header of a Draft object, when the message is actually sent, the From header is not respected and is changed to the users main account.

How can we implement "Sending From" a different address as the Gmail UI does?

thanks!

Comment: nvm this was a bug on our end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work fine as long as the From header email address portion matches one registered in the "Send mail as" setting in Gmail.